# Cannot add gmail to unmonitored apps (battery usage) to get notifications in battery saving mode

Tags: notifications, battery-life, gmail, 7.0-nougat

I want to have instant Gmail notifications even in battery saving mode (which typically blocks apps from background CPU/network usage). I found these [amazing instructions for Android 6](https://medium.com/@Gtwy/gmail-notifications-not-working-on-android-6-0-1-marshmallow-solution-inside-9315ee11b7c6), however when I try something similar on my Samsung Galaxy S7 phone (Android 7.0), i.e. I go **Settings -> Device Maintenance -> Battery -> Unmonitored Apps -> Add apps**, then I don't see Gmail app in the list!! There are lots of others but not Gmail! Chrome neither. How is it possible?? How do I solve the issue? Thanks a lot.

Timely notifications on Android is a bit of a crapshoot since Marshmallow. Thanks to the battery management, no app can guarantee that their background process will be running on the specific intervals they have set. It varies among devices though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work since I have a LG G6 and am running Oreo.  So, the way I found to allow Gmail to battery saver mode was this:
Settings --> General --> Battery --> Power Saving exclusions
Scroll down to Gmail, then click on the switch to the right.

Tested by sending myself an email from another account and I got the notification!

Source:  Had to do it myself.